# Using Regular Expression on Live Validation

Tags: regex, validation, client-side

I'm using LiveValidation (http://livevalidation.com/) to validate a form on my site in the client-side part.

However i'm having problems using the regular expressions:
the example on the website is not very clear and i'm trying to validate a field where i don't want to reject numbers with this:

```
    var f1a = new LiveValidation('nome');
f1a.add( Validate.Format, { pattern: /[a-zA-Z]/i } );
```

or at least all non digit characters: 
`[^0-9]` ???

are my regular expressions wrong?
or am i using wrongly the live validation with reg exp?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex matches input that is all alphabets.

```
/^[a-z]+$/i
```

The + is necessary for it to match multiple characters. Without it, the regex matches the first character and stops.

I recommend [this](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) website. It has a lot of samples and you can test the regex.

the `i` in the regex is the `ignoreCase` flag. When specified, matches are made irrespective of case.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. One more question, why the /i? what it does?

Comment: i stands for ignoreCase. Without it, the comparisons are case-sensitive. A wouldn't match a. In this case, the regex can be further shortened (as A and a are matched), due to the use of /i. I have edited my answer.